# How to configure Solr with Accumulo

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I was working with Solr to integrate Accumulo NoSQL database for indexing.I have gone through many sites for Accumulo connector to connect with Accumulo DB from Solr, but i didnt got any solution up to now.Can any one suggest me where can i get the connector or relevant configuration steps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Which errors did you get? What were your configuration? Did anything work at all? Did you see any request on the Solr side? On the Accumulo side?

Comment: I am getting this exception::                                                                ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter  – Delta Import Failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: 'url' is a required attribute Processing Document # 1

Comment: Which indicates that you're missing the "url" parameter in your DIH configuration..

Comment: I resolved that error and now am not facing any errors,but the data was not fetching from the DB to solr.i mean indexing was not done.